# Calling member functions dynamically

Tags: delphi

I'm pretty sure it's possible to call a class and its member function dynamically in Delphi, but I can't quite seem to make it work.  What am I missing?

```
// Here's a list of classes (some code removed for clarity)
moClassList : TList;
moClassList.Add( TClassA );
moClassList.Add( TClassB );

// Here is where I want to call an object's member function if the
// object's class is in the list:
for i := 0 to moClassList.Count - 1 do
    if oObject is TClass(moClassList[i]) then
        with oObject as TClass(moClassList[i]) do
            Foo();
```

I get an undeclared identifier for Foo() at compile.

Clarification/Additional Information:

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a Change Notification system between business classes.  Class A registers to be notified of changes in Class B, and the system stores a mapping of Class A -> Class B.  Then, when a Class B object changes, the system will call a A.Foo() to process the change.  I'd like the notification system to not require any hard-coded classes if possible.  There will always be a Foo() for any class that registers for notification.

Maybe this can't be done or there's a completely different and better approach to my problem.

By the way, this is not exactly an "Observer" design pattern because it's not dealing with objects in memory. Managing changes between related persistent data seems like a standard problem to be solved, but I've not found very much discussion about it.

Again, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: Where is the Foo() declaration?

Comment: Hi, User. Your question is a little bit difficult to understand as currently written, and so the answers you're getting are also kind of confusing.  Your question shows what you've got that's not working, but it doesn't really explain exactly what you're trying to do.  Could you please edit your question to explain that so we can come up with better answers for you?  Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer, but this is still slightly ambiguous: You're saying this is not the Observer pattern because you're not dealing with objects in memory. What are you dealing with? Are you working on an ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you're doing something very unusual with `TList`: TList is a list of UNTYPED POINTERS. You can add any pointer you want to that list, and when you're doing `moClassList.Add( TClassA )` you're actually adding a reference to the class TClassA to the list. Technically that's not wrong, it's just very unusual: I'd expect to see `TClassList` if you actually want to add a class! Or `TList<TClass>` if you're using a Delphi version that support it.

Then you're looping over the content of the list, and you're checking if `oObject` is of the type in the list. So you do want classes in that list after all. The test will work properly and test rather the object is of that type, but then when you do `with oObject as TClass(moClassList[i]) do` you're actually casting the object to... `TObject`. Not what you wanted, I'm sure!

And here you have an other problem: Using `Foo()` in that context will probably not work. `TObject` doesn't contain a Foo() method, but an other Foo() method might be available in context: That's the problem with the `with` keyword!

And to finally answer the question in the title bar: Delphi is not an Dynamic language. The compiler can't call a method it doesn't know about at compile time. You'll need to find a OOP way of expressing what you want (using simple inheritance or interfaces), or you may call the function using RTTI.

---

*Edited* after question clarification.

All your business classes need to implement some kind of notification request management, so your design benefits allot from a base class. Declare a base class that implements all you need, then derive all your business classes from it:

```
TBusinessBase = class
public
  procedure RegisterNotification(...);
  procedure UnregisterNotification(...);

  procedure Foo;virtual;abstract;
end;
```

In your initial example you'd no longer need the list of supported classes. You'll simply do:

```
oObject.Foo;
```

No need for type testing since Delphi is strongly typed. No need for casting since you can declare `oObject": TBusinessBase`.

Alternatively, if you for some reason you can't change the inheritance for all your objects, you can use interfaces.

Comment: you can interpret dynamic as delphi it self does, that is to mean polymorphic

Comment: Or you can interpret Dynamic the way [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) does. But I guess I'm covering both scenarios.

Comment: To confuse things further Delphi has the `dynamic` keyword that functions like `virtual` but has a different implementation [(link)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declspec(dynamic))

Comment: I think using interfaces would be the better solution. Thank you for puzzling out the question and giving a detailed answer. I have never played with TCLassList so the whole concept is new to me. It does sound tempting to play with.

Comment: @moz, if the problem can be solved with single inheritance, it should be solved with single inheritance: all common behavior would be implemented just once, in one single class. Using interfaces assumes multiple inheritance, so no common root, so the common behavior will be implemented multiple times. There's also the added complexity of dealing with two object lifetime management models: Interfaces are reference-counted while most other Delphi objects are "owned".

Answer (score 2):

`TClass` is defined:

```
TClass = class of TObject;
```

You then write `oObject as TClass` which is effectively a null operation since `oObject` already was a `TObject`.

What you need is something like this:

```
type
  TFoo = class
    procedure Foo();
  end;
  TFooClass = class of TFoo;
  TBar = class(TFoo)
    procedure Bar();
  end;

....

  if oObject is TFooClass(moClassList[i]) then
    with oObject as TFooClass(moClassList[i]) do
      Foo();
```

This explains why your attempts to call `Foo()` does not compile, but I simply have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Even after your clarification I'm struggling to understand the problem.

Comment: Using `Object as TClassType` immediately after `if Object is TClassType` is redundant - it is OK (and faster) to use a hard cast. What the above is effectively doing is `if Object is TClassType then if Object is TClassType then TClassType(Object).Foo`

Comment: @gerry that is correct. I was trying not to confuse OP with too many changes!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really contrived example (using an array instead of a TList) that I think is what you're trying to do (error handling and try..finally intentionally omitted for clarity).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TBaseClass=class(TObject)
    procedure Foo; virtual;
  end;

  TClassA=class(TBaseClass)
    procedure Foo; override;
  end;

  TClassB=class(TBaseClass)
    procedure Foo; override;
  end;

  TClassArray= array of TBaseClass;

{ TClassB }

procedure TClassB.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TClassB.Foo() called.');
end;

{ TClassA }

procedure TClassA.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TClassA.Foo() called.');
end;

var
  Base: TBaseClass;
  ClassArr: TClassArray;

{ TBaseClass }

procedure TBaseClass.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TBaseClass.Foo called!!!!!!!!');
end;

begin
  ClassArr := TClassArray.Create(TClassA.Create, TClassB.Create);
  for Base in ClassArr do
    Base.Foo;

  for Base in ClassArr do
    Base.Free;
  ReadLn;
end.
```